# How to configure DAV svn access?

Tags: svn

I am trying to restrict access to a repository on my local subversion server. I have set it up using Apache and `dav_svn_module` and `authz_svn_module`. Currently it's working great, users login, and can commit fine.

What I would like to achieve is a single repository which can only be read from and written to by a single user.

My `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` is as follows

```
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn

   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      # SSLRequireSSL

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion repositories"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
      Require valid-user
      AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svnauthz.conf
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

My `/etc/svnauthz.conf` looks like the following,

```
[groups]
devs = david.yell,user2,user3

[/]
$authenticated = rw
@devs = rw
* =
```

However, this is currently restricting access to every repository on the server, which is less than ideal. How do I go about configuring the access to be specific to a single repository?

Additional, this is an internal server, so although I do appreciate advice for production, it's not essential.

*Update*
I've updated my `svnauthz.conf` file now,

```
[groups]
devs = david.yell,user2,user3

[ProtectedRepo:/]
david.yell = rw
* = 

[/]
$authenticated = rw
@devs = rw
* =
```

I'm trying to use this as reference, http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html but it quotes here

> To be more specific: the value of the section-names are either of the
>   form [repos-name:path] or the form [path]. If you're using the
>   SVNParentPath directive, then it's important to specify the repository
>   names in your sections. If you omit them, then a section like
>   [/some/dir] will match the path /some/dir in every repository.

Does this mean that I need to declare every single repo on the server? Which is about 30 currently

Comment: Setup access to user for repository/path. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have this setup now. However my 'protected; repo will not allow access.

Comment: Just a remark about the "$authenticated" syntax that you use: I did not know this existed. Is this documented somewhere? I can only find it in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/authz.c

Comment: @myself: OK, I found it now: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html near the end

Answer (score 1):

> Setup per-directory access control to distinguish the permissions of user for each WEBDAV repository/path.
>
> In the case of Apache, one needs to load the mod_authz_svn module and then add the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive (within the httpd.conf file) pointing to your own rules-file. (For a full explanation, see the section called “Per-Directory Access Control”.) If you're using svnserve, then you need to make the authz-db variable (within svnserve.conf) point to your rules-file.
>
> It's possible to set up finer-grained permissions using a second Apache httpd module, mod_authz_svn. This module grabs the various opaque URLs passing from client to server, asks mod_dav_svn to decode them, and then possibly vetoes requests based on access policies defined in a configuration file.
>
> If you've built Subversion from source code, mod_authz_svn is automatically built and installed alongside mod_dav_svn. Many binary distributions install it automatically as well. To verify that it's installed correctly, make sure it comes right after mod_dav_svn's LoadModule directive in httpd.conf:

**References**

- [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)
- [Per-Directory Access Control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir)
- [subversion source: authz.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/authz.c)